# How to know which archive page is active

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have two custom post type name as 'product' and 'blog'. And I have also two archive page 'archive-product.php' and 'archive-blog.php'.

Now, I want to know which archive page is active.

Example: We know `is_page('contact')` if page is contact then it return true. But what about archive pages. I've used `is_archive('blog')`, but this function always returns true on both product archive or blog archive active.

So is there any way to know is this archive page 'product' or 'blog' is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [`is_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) does not accept any parameters if you have read the codex, that is why it will always return true no matter what you tried on any archive page

As pointed out [`is_post_type_archive( $post_types )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) is the proper conditional tag to use to check for a specific post type archive page.

One thing though, your question is unclear on how you would like to use this condition, as you already have an archive page specially made for each custom post type, so to check if your on a specific archive page would not make sense. `is_post_type_archive('blog')` will always return true on archive-blog.php while `is_post_type_archive('product')` will always return false, and `is_post_type_archive('product')` will always return true on archive-product.php while `is_post_type_archive('blog')` will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

use [is_post_type_archive](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)

```
if(is_post_type_archive('product'))
```

or

```
if(is_post_type_archive('blog'))
```